# "You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Services.Client, Version=3.5.0.0'"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm building an app using Windows Azure Table. I've encapsulated all my calls to the Table Service into its own assembly. This assembly uses the .NET 4.0 Framework and includes a reference to System.Data.Service.Client (4.0).  I'm able to use this assembly from a test project with no issue.

When I add this project as a reference to an MVC2 web application — again targeting the .NET 4.0 framework — I get the above error. I added the same DLL (v.4.0) to the web project but the problem persists.

What is going on? Why should I need to use a 3.5 DLL from the MVC project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added the following to my web.config file and all is copacetic.

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
</system.web>
```